# Using webcam as security cam

Tags: linux, webcam

I’m running a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and would like to record videos using the built-in camera.

**Requirements**:

1. Automatic creation of a new video file when the size of a previous
   one exceeds 2 GB.
2. Application needs to be stable, as it is a requirement to operate for a few weeks.

**Nice additions**:

1. Livestreaming or just saving videos to some online storage would be
   a nice feature.

It is important that the solution does not require a lot of setting up and tweaking, as I have a little turn-around time to achieve this.

Comment: VLC and a little bit of bash scripting is doing a great job on that.

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) and scripting will achieve what you are after.

I suggest using [motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) to "[operate Linux spycams as motion detectors](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html)", which  can be defined [here](https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion):

> Motion is a program that monitors the video signal from one or more
>   cameras and is able to detect if a significant part of the picture has
>   changed. Or in other words, it can detect motion.

Comment: I've used motion with a cheap tablet. Worked properly for the question's requirements. *Uploading* lots of pics and video became problematic over longer time, but that may depend on the contract with the ISP.